# EF Code First Reverse Engineering Customized templates (EF Power Tools Beta 2 )

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, t4

I'm in the process of generating POCOs from an existing pgsql database.

I want to put the generated POCOs into an own C# class library and the DbContext and mapping into a 
different project so that my POCOs have no referance to anything EF related.

I'm trying to modify the Context.tt template to specify the table schema at runtime during OnModelCreating(), because using a [Table] attribute on the generated entities would introduce a hard link to the EF library.

My problem is that I'm currently unable to retrieve the schema name from the current EnitySet. 
Here is an extract of What I've done so far :

```
var efHost = (EfTextTemplateHost)Host;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
<#
foreach (var set in efHost.EntityContainer.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
#>
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new <#= set.ElementType.Name #>Map());
  modelBuilder.Entity<<#= set.ElementType.Name #>>().ToTable("<#= set.Name #>", "<#=????#>");
<#
}
#>
    }
```

The only object available at this time is an instance of **EfTextTemplateHost**.

Any Help Appreciated.

TIA.

**EDIT** : I've found the way to retreive the schema (set.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value ?? ""), but the value is always null !
This may imply that the Reverse Enginering Code First tool does not give the value to the template host. I may end parsing an edmx file. To be continued.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the mapping.tt file that comes with the power tools, and it gets the schema by doing this:

```
var tableSet = efHost.TableSet;
var tableName = (string)tableSet.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value
    ?? tableSet.Name;
var schemaName = (string)tableSet.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value;
```

Could you do something similar?  Maybe this (haven't tried this myself):

```
<#   
foreach (var set in efHost.EntityContainer.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())   
{
#>   
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new <#= efHost.TableSet.MetadataProperties[set.ElementType.Name].Value #>Map());   
    modelBuilder.Entity<<#= efHost.TableSet.MetadataProperties[set.ElementType.Name].Value #>>().ToTable("<#= set.Name #>", "<#=efHost.TableSet.MetadataProperties[set.ElementType.Name].Value #>");   
<#   
}
#>
```